# Flex height problems when use overflow content

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I have a problem... If I use simple flex structure to keep flex ratio that I defined when i use long content, it works :
https://jsfiddle.net/4zgpnjmd/

But if I add a level, ratio are not kept and the flex with long content has a bigger ratio then others :
https://jsfiddle.net/164wckrL/1/

> ```
> html, body {
>     margin: 0;
>     height: 100%;
> }
>
> #wrap {
>     display: flex;
>     height: 100%;
> }
>
> #left-col {
>     flex: 1;
>     background: blue;
> }
>
> #right-col {
>     flex: 2;
> }
>
> #wrap-left-col {
>     display: flex;
>     height: 100%;
>     flex-direction: column;
> }
>
> header {
>     flex: 1;
>     background-color: gray;
> }
>
> #wrap-article {
>     flex: 2;
>     display: flex;
>     height: 100%;
> }
>
> #article1 {
>     flex: 2;
>     background-color: red;
>     overflow-y: auto;
>     min-height: 0px;
> }
>
> #article2 {
>     flex: 3;
>     background: yellow;
> }
>
> footer {
>     flex: 1;
>     background-color: gray;
> }
> ```

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="left-col"></div>
    <div id="right-col">
        <div id="wrap-left-col">
            <header id="header" >This is a header</header>
            <div id="wrap-article">
                <article id="article1">
                    This is the content that
                    <br />
                    With a lot of lines.
                    <br />
                    With a lot of lines.
                    <br />
                    This is the content that
                    <br />
                    With a lot of lines.
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    This is the content that
                    <br />
                    With a lot of lines.
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    This is the content that
                    <br />
                    With a lot of lines.
                    <br />
                     This is the content that
                    <br />
                    With a lot of lines.
                    <br />
                    With a lot of lines.
                    <br />
                    This is the content that
                    <br />
                    With a lot of lines.
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    This is the content that
                    <br />
                    With a lot of lines.
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    This is the content that
                    <br />
                    With a lot of lines.
                </article>
                <article id="article2"></article>
            </div>
            <footer id="footer" >This is a footer</footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyone have a solution? Thanks

Comment: This is nowhere near enough of an explanation of your problem. It will likely get closed if you don't add more detail explaining your problem including the desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are talking about vertical ratio between header, articles and footer try this :

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#wrap {
  display: flex;
  height: 75%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#left-col {
  flex: 1;
  background: blue;
}

#right-col {
  flex: 2;
}

#wrap-left-col {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#header {
  flex: 1 1 25%;
  background-color: gray;
  min-height: 25%;
}

#wrap-article {
  flex: 2 1 50%;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#article1 {
  flex: 2;
  background-color: red;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#article2 {
  flex: 2;
  background: yellow;
}

#footer {
  flex: 1 1 25%;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="left-col"></div>
  <div id="right-col">
    <div id="wrap-left-col">
      <header id="header">This is a header</header>
      <div id="wrap-article">
        <article id="article1">
          This is the content that
          <br /> With a lot of lines.
          <br /> With a lot of lines.
          <br /> This is the content that
          <br /> With a lot of lines.
          <br />
          <br /> This is the content that
          <br /> With a lot of lines.
          <br />
          <br /> This is the content that
          <br /> With a lot of lines.
          <br /> This is the content that
          <br /> With a lot of lines.
          <br /> With a lot of lines.
          <br /> This is the content that
          <br /> With a lot of lines.
          <br />
          <br /> This is the content that
          <br /> With a lot of lines.
          <br />
          <br /> This is the content that
          <br /> With a lot of lines.
        </article>
        <article id="article2"></article>
      </div>
      <footer id="footer">This is a footer</footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```